# dc.js crossfilter not working when i separate the dc.js graphs into multiple .js files

Tags: javascript, html, dc.js, crossfilter

Firstly, i thank everyone who helped and guided me in dc.js as i'm pretty new to coding stuff. Thankfully, i have created multiple dc.js charts and it works fine.

I tried separating the graphs into individual .js file, like my barchart will be in barchart.js, stackedbar will be in stacked.js and so on..
Same like i have separate HTML and CSS and in my HTML i'm calling every individual .js (including my separated graphs). 
The graphs are rendering when i run the HTML file. But the problem is it is not crossfiltering with eachother.

Whereas when i have all the dc.js graphs (bar, stacked, bubble etc.) in one javascript file then the crossfilter works.

My Question here is : Is it not possible to crossfilter when the graphs as separated in to different .js files?

The reason i'm separating the graphs in to different .js file is to have the code changes easy as they are separate files.

Can someone suggest me with good option.

Comment: This is possible. You'll need to share a example showing what you're doing (preferably JSFiddle or a similar editable platform, but a Github repo is fine as well) in order to tell you what the problem is.

Comment: As @EthanJewett says, this should not be a problem but it's hard to say what's going wrong without looking at your code. Make sure that you're still using the same instance of crossfilter for all the charts? You don't want to copy and paste that part; share the data somehow.